# Grails @Resource throwing GroovyCastException on PUT

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following domain object:

```
package example.rest

import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri="/departments", formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Department {

String displayName
Integer locationId
Boolean showModal

static mapping = {
    id generator: "assigned"
    table "departments"
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    showModal nullable: true
    displayName nullable: true
    locationId nullable: true
}
}
```

GET's work ok, but PUT's are throwing the following exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - GroovyCastException occurred when processing        request: [PUT] /example-rest/departments/21
Cannot cast object 'example.rest.DepartmentController$_update_closure7@6e36bf53' with class 'example.rest.DepartmentController$_update_closure7' to class 'example.rest.DepartmentController'. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'example.rest.DepartmentController$_update_closure7@6e36bf53' with class 'example.rest.DepartmentController$_update_closure7' to class 'example.rest.DepartmentController'
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a very new feature - you're probably better off asking on the User mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar problem when I was fixing http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10972 . Your problem should be fixed in Grails 2.3.5 (to be released by the end of this week) . Fixed by commit https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/d073a93b .

Make sure that grails.mime.types setting in Config.groovy is also updated. It must be done manually. See [GRAILS-10973](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10973?focusedCommentId=79061&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-79061).

Answer (score 0):

Your use case works great in Grails 2.3.4. Tried with the below PUT request:

```
curl -i -X PUT 
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
        -d '{"displayName": "Test", "locationId": 1,"showModal": false}' 
        http://localhost:8080/DemoApp/departments/1
```

Assuming there is a department with id 1 already persisted. Specify your request payload to look at, if that helps.